# Need Column format for formatting date sharepoint online sharepoint default format is 10/30/2020 I need it as Oct 30, 2020

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, modern-ui

I am trying to format the date from 10/30/2020 to Oct 30, 2020 using the SharePoint online column formatting. Can someone please help me out with JSON format which convert my date to any specific format which was passed as a parameter.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Dinesh Talekar,

Please take a reference of below JSON code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "=if(getMonth(@currentField)==0, 'Jan', if(getMonth(@currentField)==1, 'Feb', if(getMonth(@currentField)==2, 'Mar', if(getMonth(@currentField)==3, 'Apr', if(getMonth(@currentField)==4, 'May', if(getMonth(@currentField)==5, 'Jun', if(getMonth(@currentField)==6, 'Jul', if(getMonth(@currentField)==7, 'Aug', if(getMonth(@currentField)==8, 'Sep', if(getMonth(@currentField)==9, 'Oct', if(getMonth(@currentField)==10, 'Nov', 'Dec')))))))))))+ ' '+getDate(@currentField)+','+ getYear(@currentField)",
    "style": {
        "color": "#ff0000"
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

BR

Comment: @baker-kong-msft - if my date is consider 11/3/2020 so it is showing Nov 4, 2020 its wrong